# How to get configurable product options on associated product page?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, associated-products, google-product-feeds, google-shopping

I'm working with Magento 1.9 store with google merchant (google shopping).

I'm getting price mismatch for associated products because I'm sending them to google feed instead of their configurable products.

Associated products are not visible but I have a rule to redirect their url key to their configurable products so customers will land on the configurable page with options instead of simple product view with no other options.

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

Make associated products to be visible in (search and catalog) and show all information (image, title, short description, etc) with the parent configurable options like: **size** and **color**, and when customer switch to different size and color the selected item will reflect on the page with its title, image, price, short description, etc.

The objective to show google merchant that the page exist and its matching the price in the feed, also allow customers to see other options as well.

Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to build product URLs for each product variant using the configurable product's `URL Key` since the associated products are `not visible individually`.

Append the following parameters to the configurable product's URL to automatically select product options and display the correct price for the variant when the page loads:
`#[attribute_id]=[attribute_value_id]&[attribute_id]=[attribute_value_id]`

Example for a shirt:
**Attribute Code**: *color* (attribute_id of 142)
**Attribute Value**: *Blue* (attribute_value_id of 2034)

**Attribute Code**: *size* (attribute_id of 150)
**Attribute Value**: *Large* (attribute_value_id of 1180)

**Original URL**:
https://www.domain.com/designer-shirt

**New URL**:
https://www.domain.com/designer-shirt#142=2034&150=1180

Once that's done, you should be able to use the Automatic Items Updates (price and availability) assuming you have the proper microdata implemented on your product pages.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, its a good idea, I might consider it for a temporary solution. However I want the associated products to be visible on catalog and search.  When customers land on the page they will be able to see simple product page as well as configurable options to switch between products.

Comment: @Aboodred1 Is the only reason for this because of disapproved products in Google Merchant Center due to the price mismatch? Are your product pages marked up with microdata to allow for the use of Automatic Item Updates (such as price)?

Comment: Yes they are marker up with microdata